# I created libgdx project with no compilation errors, but I can't run it

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I created libgdx project
using [this link](http://chrismweb.com/2011/10/18/how-to-start-creating-android-games-using-the-libgdx-game-development-framework/) in Eclipse with no compilation errors.

I pressed ctrl-F11. It does not run.
A window to convert to ordinal desktop and android projects appeared.
I did it.
I imported them to Eclipse as help screen required.
It seems I should hit ctrl-F11 for this new project.
But I can't run it  because of error
"libgdx com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener can not be resolved"
in line:
new LwjglApplication(new DesktopStarter(), cfg);

BTW, there is no "ApplicationListener" in "com.badlogic.gdx." in new converted project.

So what is with desktop app?
How to run it? What 's the problem?
(Hmm. Should I really do all that each time to run my app?
Running such libgdx app via converting it 
to usual desktop or android app looks me very uncomfortable)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*AndroidApplicationConfiguration.java* is a part of **gdx-backend-android** and you are trying to use it with the **LWJGL backend**. This is the reason you are not able to run this project for the desktop version.

Remove any AndroidApplicationConfiguration objects that you are passing to the desktop version. This should make it work.

*Just a tip*

Create two different constructors in your main project:

1 - one for the android with AndroidApplicationConfiguration as one of the parameters.

2 - and the other one without the AndroidApplicationConfiguration (you won't be needing that on the desktop any way)

Use the android version for your android project and the desktop version for the desktop project.

Comment: Yes. After excluding this library the app started in a window. But black screen and lot of runtime errors: MyLibGDXGame: Game2.create()
Exception in thread "Thread-3" javax.media.opengl.GLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject
 at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:271)
 at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.maybeDoSingleThreadedWorkaround(GLCanvas.java:410)
 at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:244)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogl.JoglAnimator.display(JoglAnimator.java:155)
........etc

Comment: The "gwt" code in that backtrace is for building HTML5-based GWT apps, not for a dekstop app.  Check out the official tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup

Comment: @user993354 If you remove those html5 libraries, is your project working fine then?? I think that you are using some function of the html5 libraries and that is why it is giving you these errors. Including libraries shouldn't give you any errors until you use them in wrong places/wrong way.